# Working with query to archive customer data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Customers` table, a `Transactions` table, and a `Payments` table. The `Transactions` table represents charges to a customer, and the `Payments` table represents credits to a customer. (Both tables have foreign keys to the `Customers` table.)

A customer's balance is calculated using `Customers.StartingBalance`, plus the sum of all that customer's charges in the `Transactions` table, minus the sum of all that customer's payments in the `Payments` table.

Now I want to implement an archive feature that deletes all transactions and payments prior to a given date, and then updates `Customers.StartingBalance` so that the final balance (calculated as described in the previous paragraph) remains the same.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ArchiveData] @ArchiveDateTime DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CustomerBalance TABLE
    (
        CustomerId INT,
        Amount BIGINT
    );

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Archive transactions
    DELETE Transactions WITH (TABLOCK)
    OUTPUT deleted.CustomerId, deleted.TotalAmount INTO @CustomerBalance
    WHERE [TimeStamp] < @ArchiveDateTime;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CustomerBalance)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Customers SET StartingBalance = StartingBalance +
            (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @CustomerBalance cb WHERE Id = cb.CustomerId)
    END;

    DELETE FROM @CustomerBalance

    -- Archive payments
    DELETE Payments WITH (TABLOCK)
    OUTPUT deleted.CustomerId, deleted.Amount INTO @CustomerBalance
    WHERE [Date] < @ArchiveDateTime;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CustomerBalance)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Customers SET StartingBalance = StartingBalance -
            (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @CustomerBalance cb WHERE Id = cb.CustomerId)
    END;

    -- Probably not needed
    DELETE FROM @CustomerBalance

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Since SQL is not my core competency, I'd like to get feedback on this. Does it seem "correct"? Does it seem optimal? Also, I'm not sure about clauses like the following.

```
UPDATE Customers SET StartingBalance = StartingBalance -
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @CustomerBalance cb WHERE Id = cb.CustomerId)
```

1. What does this do where `@CustomerBalance` contains no rows for the customer?
2. What does this do where `@CustomerBalance` contains multiple rows for the customer?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your last question

```
-- i would add the name of the outer query table in the inner one
UPDATE Customers 
SET StartingBalance = StartingBalance -  (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
                                          FROM @CustomerBalance cb 
                                          WHERE Customers.Id = cb.CustomerId);
```

As you are using an aggregation function, the inner query will give you the sum of all the rows found for the client. And  0 if  no row is found.